# Friedman test block contents

Tags: nonparametric, blocking, friedman-test

For comparing computational intelligence algorithms over multiple functions I have seen the Friedman test used like the following [1]:

```
           Algorithm1 Algorithm2 ... Algorithmk
Function1  mean(A1F1) mean(A2F1) ... mean(AkF1)
Function2  mean(A1F2) mean(A2F2) ... mean(AkF2)
...
Functionn  mean(A1Fn) mean(A2Fn) ... mean(AkFn)
```

where mean(x) is the mean result over a number of runs (say M).

However the wikipedia page says that there should be "a single observation at the intersection of each block and treatment". So I was thinking something like:

```
                Algorithm1 Algorithm2 ... AlgorithmK
Function1_run1  A1F1_run1  A2F1_run1  ... AKF1_run1
Function1_run2  A1F1_run2  A2F1_run2  ... AKF1_run2
...
Function1_runM  A1F1_runM  A2F1_runM  ... AkF1_runM

Function2_run1  A1F2_run1  A2F2_run1  ... AKF2_run1
Function2_run2  A1F2_run2  A2F2_run2  ... AKF2_run2
...
Function2_runM  A1F2_runM  A2F2_runM  ... AkF2_runM

FunctionN_run1  A1FN_run1  A2FN_run1  ... AKFN_run1
FunctionN_run2  A1FN_run2  A2FN_run2  ... AKFN_run2
...
FunctionN_runM  A1FN_runM  A2FN_runM  ... AkFN_runM
```

Each run is completely independent from every other run.

My questions are: 
Is the second method valid for the Friedman test?
If so, can the order of the runs be changed for a given function since they are independent?

[1] S. García, D. Molina, M. Lozano, F. Herrera, A Study on the Use of Non-Parametric Tests for Analyzing the Evolutionary Algorithms' Behaviour: A Case Study on the CEC'2005 Special Session on Real Parameter Optimization. Journal of Heuristics, 15 (2009) 617-644.

[2] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedman_test

Comment: Once means are taken in each cell, you do have 'only a single observation'. I don't know why one would do this, rather than adapt the Friedman test to the situation at hand, but it should be valid as far as the hypothesis test itself goes (one might need to beware the ecological fallacy in applying the conclusions more generally, however it probably doesn't impact your situation).

Comment: When you say "I don't know why one would do this" do you mean taking the average result? And how would the Friedman test be adapted?

Comment: Yes, I mean taking the average result. Adapted in the sense of taking some other statistic with the same general purpose as the Friedman test and performing a permutation test.